# VBA FormulaArray - Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

At first, I am trying to write a macro program which can let user use to find numbers that closest to a total target that input from user.

- in the first figure, the quantity column is presenting amounts for their own title respectively. Target is an input from user. the horizontal A,B,C,D is use to show user which Title used.

[image]

I get this error message after the file execution.

[image]

Any advice? Thanks...

```
Sub Option1()
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 5 To 8
        Sheet1.Cells(5, c).FormulaArray = _
          "=INDEX(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(C2,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2)*TRANSPOSE(R2C2:R9C2),MATCH(MIN(ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(C2,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2),R2C2:R9C2)-R1C5)),ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(C2,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2),R2C2:R9C2)-R1C5),0),0)"
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you should clear the existing array before ? You can't change part of an existing array.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply to the whole range directly, not in each cell :

```
Sub Option1()
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(5,5),Sheet1.Cells(5, 8)).Clear
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(5,5),Sheet1.Cells(5, 8)).FormulaArray = _
       "=INDEX(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(C2,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2)*TRANSPOSE(R2C2:R9C2),MATCH(MIN(ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(C2,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2),R2C2:R9C2)-R1C5)),ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(C2,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2),R2C2:R9C2)-R1C5),0),0)"

End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub Option2()
    Sheet1.Range("E5:I5").Clear
    Sheet1.Range("E5:I5").FormulaArray = _
       "=INDEX(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(R2C3,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2)*TRANSPOSE(R2C2:R9C2),MATCH(MIN(ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(R2C3,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2),R2C2:R9C2)-R1C5)),ABS(MMULT(MOD(INT((ROW(R2C2:INDEX(R2C3,2^ROWS(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)/2^(TRANSPOSE(MATCH(ROW(R2C2:R9C2),ROW(R2C2:R9C2)))-1)),2),R2C2:R9C2)-R1C5),0),0)"

End Sub
```

Comment: @Empty : What is the error? I've added a line to empty the range first

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class

Comment: @Empty : I think the issue now is your formula. you have most of in `R1C1` refs but you also have a few like `INDEX(C2`, you should have all of the refs in the same style.

Comment: I will try to work on that. Hope can get it right. Thanks :)

Comment: @Empty : I changed the `INDEX(C2` into `INDEX(R2C3` in the `Option2`, try it! ;)

Comment: @R3uK You're kidding... the problem was in a **422** character formula. _shocking_

Comment: @reasra Thanks for the advice, the run-time error '1004': Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class here is because of the length of Formula had over exceed the maximum (255)...

Comment: @Empty : Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @R3uK version 2016

Comment: @Empty : Ok... Strange, I'd have said that this wasn't an issue anymore... For **Excel 2007 to 2016, Length of formula contents: 8,192 characters and Internal length of formula: 16,384 bytes**. Does the code work with a shorter formula?

Comment: I had tried for a week to workout with this issue, unfortunately I still get the similar error. I guess I need help from here..

Comment: @Empty : have you tried with a shorter formula? Pick a simple one and try  with!

Comment: @R3uK: I've give up using formula. I'm using VBA code. The problem was solved. Thanks for the advise from all for these few weeks. Appreciated.

Comment: @Empty : Ok, glad you found a solution even if it was on your own! ;)

Comment: @Empty : And a little upvote would be very heart warming! ;)